# Make Clear to user which areas covered without keyword stuffing

Tags: seo, keywords, content, schema.org, blackhat

Hi we have a catering website one of our main niches is birthday party catering. One of our main selling points is that we cover all suburbs and towns.

It is essential for us (or at least for my boss) that we include all areas we cover on the page. My boss hammers me to do the following (see image) which I have done...but I don't like it one bit since I see it as keyword stuffing.

[image]

**My Question**

1. Is this a form of keyword stuffing?
2. Since as per client / boss request he insists on having the following (see img) on the page, if it is a form of keyword stuffing what are my options to make it less "spammy"?
3. Would using a schema markup perhaps help resolve the issue for me? If yes can anyone give me an example of how I would tackle above problem with schema.org

Thank you for taking the time to read

Comment: I do not work in these areas or I would jump in with both feet. Someone will come along. It tends to be a little slow on weekends sometimes. I up-voted this question to give it some attention. There is an answer for this. I suspect that schema.org mark-up will be the best solution. I rather suspect that listing service areas like this once will not be keyword stuffing, however, I would rather see something more formal just in case.

Comment: Pointless, Google now uses local searches, your get the same results without spamming those locations by informing Google your radius of reach.

Answer (score 1):

Listing all areas you cover might be useful. But your screenshot shows more than that: instead of listing just the areas, you include (variations of) the business keywords, too. *That* I’d consider spammy (but I can’t speak for all search engines).

Someone reading your list already knows what services you provide, so why should it be repeated for every area? It would only make sense if you don’t provide every service for every area, but in that case it might be better to group the list accordingly.

I’d use something like this:

> **We also cater in other areas of Sydney:**
>
> - Central Business District
> - Eastern Sydney
> - Forest District
> - …
>
> **Not in Sidney? We also offer catering services in:**
>
> - Melbourne
> - Perth
> - …

---

If you want to provide structured data with Schema.org, you could use the [`areaServed` property](http://schema.org/areaServed):

> The geographic area where a service or offered item is provided.

Comment: I find this answer perfect to your problem. In case your boss insists on doing it the other way he really does not know how people react to a webpage ( leaving the keyword stuffing problem aside). For example I can easily understand and read the list above, but in your screenshot non only that I do not really understand it, more to that I would quickly hit the back button. The above list is user friendly, which is all that counts.